# Polygon-Line Collision Detection

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to find a formula to determine if a line intersects a polygon.  I have tried, but the code below is not working properly.

```
bool Check_Collision(float x1,float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
        int j=MyPolyVector.size()-1;
        for (int i=0;i<MyPolyVector.size();i++)
        {
                float x3=MyPolyVector[i].X;
                float x4=MyPolyVector[j].X;
                float y3=MyPolyVector[i].Y;
                float y4=MyPolyVector[j].Y;

                float denom= ((y4-y3)*(x2-x1))-((x4-x3)*(y2-y1));
                float ua = (((x4-x3)*(y1-y3))-((y4-y3)*(x1-x3)))/denom;
                float ub = (((x2-x1)*(y1-y3))-((y2-y1)*(x1-x3)))/denom;
                j=i;

                if(ua >= 0.0f && ua <= 1.0f && ub >= 0.0f && ub <= 1.0f) return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this link might be interesting for you, to get the know-how:
[Point in Polygon Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

There is also a linked resource, for the C-Code:
[Point in Polygon - C Code](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html)

This problem is mostly handled in OpenGL context and the main idea to solve this, is counting the intersections of the polygon and of any straight line, which goes through your point to check.

How much geometry do you have to check, wether a point is inside a polygon?

PS: I just found this post about this issue :-)
[Stackoverflow - Point in Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Comment: Thx for the response but they are different things.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to have a look at [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605940) and also search for line line intersection 2D and range checking before your computation.

Also, your code requires division by zero check and further considerations about reciprocal line dimensions and tolerances.

Comment: I m checking the book now. Can you pls explain the division by zero check.

Comment: Since you will use it for division, you should check whether denom is zero or not..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have **incorrect equations** for the line intersections.  I think that the correct equations are listed **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27388/intersection-of-2-lines-in-2d-via-general-form-linear-equations)**.

That is, *a good approach to this problem is to see whether the line intersects any of the line segments on the polygon*.  So to test this, calculate the point of intersection for the line with each line of the polygon edge, and if ever this point is within the segment of the polygon, then there's an intersection (see whether the point is within the bounds defined by the end points of the segment).  (And maybe this is what you're trying to do, but it's a bit hard to tell since you give no explanation.)